# setInterval function not stopping

Tags: javascript

```
Level1();
var lvl1count = 0;
function Level1() {

    var x = setInterval(function () {
        lvl1count++;
        var x = 84 + (Math.random() * (cw - 27));
        var y = 84 + (Math.random() * (ch - 27));
        Enemies.add(new Enemy(x, y, 1, 90));
    }, 1000);
    if (lvl1count == 4) {
        console.log("finish");
        clearInterval(x);return;
    }
}
```

i am trying to add an object to a collection every 1000 ms when there is 4 object added i want to clear the Interval and stop the function but i am having the problem and the `setInterval` function is not stopping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the if check is not inside of the code that is being updated. `if (lvl1count == 4)` is only checked when `Level1` is called. Move the check inside of your interval and it will work. You also need to change your variable names so they do not conflict.

```
function Level1() {

    var timer = setInterval(function () {
        lvl1count++;
        var x = 84 + (Math.random() * (cw - 27));
        var y = 84 + (Math.random() * (ch - 27));
        Enemies.add(new Enemy(x, y, 1, 90));

        if (lvl1count == 4) {
            console.log("finish");
            clearInterval(timer);
            return;
        }


    }, 1000);
}
var lvl1count = 0;
Level1();
```

Comment: +1. A -1 to this answer ad no explanation just for the variable collision is unfair. Probably, instead of a downvote, a simple comment pointing out the problem would be more helpful also for the OP

Answer (score 0):

your latest `if` statement is executed just once, when you call the `Level1` function. So you need to check the counter (the `lvl1count` variable) everytime you call the function inside `setInterval`:

```
var x = setInterval(function () {
    lvl1count++;
    var x = 84 + (Math.random() * (cw - 27));
    var y = 84 + (Math.random() * (ch - 27));
    Enemies.add(new Enemy(x, y, 1, 90));

    if (lvl1count == 4) {
      console.log("finish");
      clearInterval(x);
      return;
    }
}, 1000);
```

Note: as pointed out by @epascarello this would require a change for a variable name. Since you already use `x` inside the anonimous function, change the setInterval assignment using another variable e.g.

```
var anotherVariable = setInterval(function () {
```

and

```
clearInterval(anotherVariable);
```

Comment: downvoter cares to explain his downvote? So I can improve my answer if necessary.

Comment: Not the downvoter, but your code will still not clear the interval.

Comment: @epascarello so why this code stops when it arrives at 4? http://codepen.io/anon/pen/IdfHt

Comment: Because YOUR code in the example !== the code in your answer above! That is why it works.

Comment: @FabrizioCalderan So you still do not see your problem? If you read my downvoted answer you know what the error is. lol

Comment: The clue is in my answer.

Comment: Oh, Now I see: the `x`

Answer (score 0):

in your case u can use the setTimeout instead the setInterval like this

```
Level1();
var lvl1count = 0;
function Level1() {

    setTimeout(function () {
        lvl1count++;
        //stuff
        if(lvl1count++ <= 5) {
            Level1();
        }
    }, 1000);
}
```